# Redirect subdomain to a subfolder inside it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect from subdomain `test.domain.com` to `test.domain.com/folder`.

Folders structure:

```
public_html
    test
        folder
        .htaccess
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /folder [L]
```

and:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 / https://test.domain.com/folder
```

but this didn't work and generated a wrong URL `https://test.domain.com/folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolder`

What is the right way to redirect from subdomain to a subfolder inside it?

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule  !^folder/ folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`